# Exported attribute in activity of android apps

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi we know that an activity of an app can be called from an outside application by means of setting the activity 
attribute value to true. But if no such attribute is specified what is the default behavior? Can the actibity still be called from outside?

Answer (score 0):

The default value depends on whether the service contains intent filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the service is intended only for application-internal use (since others would not know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the service is intended for external use, so the default value is "true".

collected from [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html)

Comment: Hi I am curious to know if I actually know the class name, in my own code off-course I do, then what will happen?